# Interceptor in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, interceptor

I want to know if there is an interceptor in JSF (like we use in Spring), and how to do we implement it?

Comment: There is unlikely to be a one-to-one mapping. Have a look at [PhaseListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could implement a [`PhaseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) for this. You could program  them to listen on a [specific JSF phase](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseId.html) which you specify in the overridden [`getPhaseId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html#getPhaseId%28%29) method. You can intercept on the before and after phase events by [`beforePhase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html#beforePhase%28javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent%29) and [`afterPhase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html#afterPhase%28javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent%29) methods.

The below example listens on the render response phase:

```
public class RequestInterceptor implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // Do your job here which should run before the render response phase.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // Do your job here which should run after the render response phase.
    }

}
```

To get it to run, you need to register it as a `<phase-listener>` in the `<life-cycle>` section of the `faces-config.xml` file. You can have multiple `<phase-listener>`s.

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.example.RequestInterceptor</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

You can specify [`PhaseId.ANY_PHASE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseId.html#ANY_PHASE) in `getPhaseId()` to let the phase listener run on every single JSF phase (note that not necessarily *all* of them will always be executed, that depends on the request type). You can if necessary get the current phase ID in the before and after phase methods by [`PhaseEvent#getPhaseId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseEvent.html#getPhaseId%28%29).

```
public class PhaseDebugger implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Before phase " + event.getPhaseId());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("After phase " + event.getPhaseId());
    }

}
```

Alternatively, a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) should work equally good if you want a more global hook (and thus you're not exactly interested in JSF requests/responses and you do not need anything from the `FacesContext`).

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class RequestInterceptor implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) {
        // Initialize global variables if necessary.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Do your job here which should run before the request processing.
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        // Do your job here which should run after the request processing.
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Cleanup global variables if necessary.
    }

}
```