# Servlet Filter - Implementing session timeout

Tags: servlets

I'm trying to use the servlet filter to implement catching of session timeout error that is not being caught within any JSF applications that is running in our web app.  The code is fairly straight forward (See below).  When the filter caught the ServletException it checks to see if it is a RuntimeException.  If it is, it checks if session has expired.  If so, it treats the error as timeout error and forward the request to the /errorpage_viewexpired.jsp.  This code works perfectly on my local pc.  But when it is running in our QA box, it sometime takes user to /errorpage_viewexpired.jsp.  But in most case, it simple takes user to a blank screen with the word null on it.  Since it is not happening on my local, I'm puzzled.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } 
    catch (ServletException e) {
       Throwable rootCause = e.getRootCause();
       if (rootCause instanceof RuntimeException) { // Catch jsf exception.
           if (isSessionExpired(request)) {
               RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/errorpage_viewexpired.jsp");
               dispatcher.forward(request, response);
           }
           else {
               rootCause.printStackTrace();
               RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/errorpage_throwable.jsp?log=N");
               dispatcher.forward(request, response);
           }
       } 
       else {
           throw e;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: in jsf you should prefer interceptors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709107/interceptor-in-jsf

Comment: one more issue I've with this is that when session timeout occurred, I'm not getting the ViewExpiredException.  I the SystemOut.log, I'll get something like this: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [/addDevices.jsp] in application [MyAccount]. Exception created : [javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Cannot get value for expression '#{addDevicesBean.orderBean.packageSummaryTable}'.  I'm not sure this is because I'm using t:saveState or what.

Comment: I'll preferred to be able to check for viewExpiredException.  Is there a way in jsf interceptors to check for this?