# How can I intercept all RichFaces requests prior to submission and rewrite the actual form values?

Tags: javascript, richfaces

I want to encode all RichFaces AJAX request values prior to submission using a custom encoding, and decode it server side.

Is there a central way both on the client and on the server to do it application wide?

Or is it possible in JSF to write a custom encoder/decoder for the form tag `enctype` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RichFaces use `RichFaces.ajax()` for AJAX submissions, you can intercept that.

As for the server side, you should implement a `PhaseListener`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8712007/1818198) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this. Can I just override it like `(function(){var tmp = RichFaces.ajax; RichFaces.ajax = function(source, event, options) { encodeStuff(); return tmp.apply(this, source, event, options); } })();` Will this capture all RichFaces submissions to the server? How can I get the form values?

Comment: It will capture all AJAX requests made by RichFaces, for whole form submits there is `RichFaces.submitForm()`. `source` is the id of the element, you'll have to traverse it and look for inputs.

Comment: Makhiel can you tell me when exactly RichFaces does whole form submits and uses RichFaces.submitForm() instead of .ajax()? Also looking into the answer you linked, to me it looks like the PhaseListener will capture both, right?