# How can I override RichFaces.ajax() such that I can manipulate form values prior to submission?

Tags: javascript, ajax, richfaces

I'm trying the following as recommended by Makhiel in [How can I intercept all RichFaces requests prior to submission and rewrite the form values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696405)

```
(function() {
  var originalRichFacesAjax = RichFaces.ajax;
  RichFaces.ajax = function(source, event, options) {
    console.log(source);
    // TODO manipulateFormValues();
    originalRichFacesAjax.call(this, source, event, options);
  }
})();
```

But actually `source` does not contain the id of the form but only the id of the button or page element I clicked on which triggered the AJAX request. How can I get the actual form values? I tried to read the RichFaces.ajax() code but I got stuck and could not find the place where it accesses the actual form.

Thanks

Comment: Then you can access parent form like this : document.getElementById(source).form

Comment: yavuzkavus that seems far too unreliable and fragile. not every element that triggers an AJAX request is a child of a form and even if it is then its parent form isn't necessarily the only form executed during the AJAX request. I need a robust general solution. Is it really so hard to intercept the AJAX request?